# '#error' statement in header file not working

Tags: c, clion

I have created a .c and a .h file with the same name. The .c file includes the header file and a main.c file includes both.

I want to put this statement in the header:

```
#ifndef TIMEOUT
    #error TIMEOUT not set
#endif
```

To force the user to specify a TIMEOUT when compiling. The problem is that CLion says gives a red line under 'error' and says 'TIMEOUT not set'.

The weird thing is that up until now all my projects have used this. The difference is that the variables behind '#ifndef' and '#define' etc. have become dark green, whereas in my previous projects these were always grey.

Have I changed a setting to something not correct? Making a new project does not solve this problem.

Let me know if I should add screenshots, thanks in advance!

Comment: *Is* `TIMEOUT` defined in your project? When and where do you define it?

Comment: gcc -o connection_manager main.c -DTIMEOUT=15

This is the command I use to compile the code. if -DTIMEOUT isn't specified it should give an error.

Comment: With most C/C++ IDEs you can set the defines you're using in the project settings. It can probably be done with CLion too.

Comment: You don't show all the code, including the `#undef TIMEOUT`.  Please make a minimal, complete example of the problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I will do that.